# Проблема со стилизацией Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

[image: Скрин конструктора]

```
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="316"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ListBox Background="#20201f" Grid.Column="1">
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <ItemsControl>
                        <Grid x:Name="gridIn">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Foreground="White">Проект 1</Label>
                            <ProgressBar Grid.Row="3" Value="20" Height="40"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
            <!--<StackPanel>
           <ListBox Name="progressBarList" Margin="5" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"/>
         </StackPanel>-->
        </Grid>
```

Как растянуть прогресс бар на всю указанную область? `<ListBoxItem>` показывает 100%, `<ItemsControl>` уже показывает `width` как у прогресс бара. В чем загвоздка и как растянуть?

Comment: ListBox'у HorizontalContentAlignment в Stretch

Comment: @EvgeniyZ без изменений, по дефолту они разве не в Stretch?

Comment: У вас со вложенностью элементов треш какой-то, очень сомневаюсь, что вам нужна такая структура...

Comment: @АндрейNOP  Полность с вами согласен, но увы, по другому пока что не получается

Comment: Изначально HorizontalContentAlignment установлен в Left. Не знаю, что у вас там без изменений, но [моя проверка доказала](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlZhp.png), что все же изменения есть...

Comment: Поясните. В чем смысл использования ItemsControl, если вы задаете его содержимое вручную? ItemsControl это не панель.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Не задаю вручную, но [код](https://github.com/MACTEPwar/ReadAndVerify/blob/master/ReadAndVerify/MainWindow.xaml) исправил, на более удобный.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вопрос решен, можно ответом.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Это вопрос дубликат, который уже благополучно закрыт. Тут нечему отвечать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ тогда спасибо большое, за то что направили в правильное русло!!!